# Changing state of parent from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, frameset, history.js

I am making an app that uses framesets. The problem that I was facing was that everytime I refreshed the page, the main frame was redirected to index.php from the present url in the frame. A reload frame would do the trick, but thats not a very good convenient solution at that.

To work around this issue I thought of using html5 browser state changes. Changing the url of the parent frame is not a concern but that does not change the state. A simple refresh would again redirect the entire thing to the index page. I tried using history.js to push the present url of the main frame to the history, so that everytime i refresh or go back whatever, it will at least stay on the same page.

The problem is i cant figure out how to change the state of the parent from the child frame. Both the parent and the child url reside on the same domain. Is it possible to do it with history.js ? If so how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `frameset`s are not supported by HTML5, so you can't use any HTML5 features with them. Please also clarify your question, now you have `frameset`s and `iframe`s, it's confusing...

Comment: the frame contents are in html5 and they support the history states perfectly fine. The app i am talking about has two frames. A main frame and a supporting frame. Main in the sense that it is the one where the pages are rendered. The supporting frame only has a few supporting features. 

I am trying to set the state of the parent from the child frame

Comment: [W3C Obsolete features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)

Comment: Well, i know its not an excellent practice or something but on same time I cant afford to change the setup as of now due to the huge code base accumulated over a year. So based on the existing scenario, if you can suggest something that would help solve the issue at hand it would be of great help;

Answer (score 0):

You can have a reference to the parent window within the iFrame by:

```
parentWindow = window.parent;
```

From there on, you can call any functions from your iFrame that have direct impact on your parent like this:

```
parentWindow.location.reload();
```

**UPDATE**

In the case that you want to preserve the state of the iFrame then that complecates things a little. You need to send it(state of the iFrame) to the parent, and then do a form submit that will send the state of the Iframe to the server. Then the response of the server should load the iFrame in its proper state.

Comment: I am more specifically trying to handle the refresh and preserve the state of the frame so that they are not redirected to the first url of the frame.